# Arrayadapter y android fragment

Tags: android, arrayadapter

Tengo un fragment con el siguiente código, el problema que tengo es que las lineas

```
ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
```

y

```
ruta = (Spinner) ruta.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

me genera error, lo probe en una actividad y funciona correctamente, el problema es que no entiendo como hacer la compatibilidad con un fragment

```
public class Valorar extends Fragment {

        Connection con;
        Spinner ruta;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            String ip = "mssql4.gear.host";
            String db = "ciclomapp1";
            String un = "ciclomapp1";
            String passwords = "Mk36-9DX-580";
            ruta = (Spinner) ruta.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

            String query = "select nombre from Rutas";
            try {
                con = connectionclass (un, passwords, db, ip);
                stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String id = rs.getString("nombre");
                    data.add(id);
                }
                String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
                ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
                ruta.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }


        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Connection connection = null;
            String ConnectionURL = null;
            try
            {
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server +"/"+ database + ";user=" + user+ ";password=" + password + ";";
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
            }
            catch (SQLException se)
            {
                Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return connection;
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_valorar, container, false);
        }

        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que error, es importante lo comentes porque podrían ser infinidad de causas. Agrega el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se te esta yendo un poco lo que es un fragmento en Android checa [esto](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)
quizás te cueste trabajo porque esta en inglés pero tienes que comprender lo que es un fragmento y como funciona en un aplicación.

Igual te explico a grandes rasgos.

un fragmento es un *pedazo de interfaz* el cuál tiene su propio layout y este necesita estar **contenido** en una actividad, por si sólo el fragmento no podría estar...

Lo que te esta pasando es que estas tratando de hacer una referencia a un elemento de una vista que el fragmento "no sabe" que tiene, para que se de cuenta de que ese elemento esta en su layout tienes que ***inflar la vista*** dentro del `onCreateView` del fragmento:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // root es una referencia a tu layout donde estan los elementos que necesitas
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mi_fragment_layout, container, false);

      // para poder usar/hacer referencia a los elementos tienes que hacerlo mediante la variable root
        Spinner ruta = (Spinner) root.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        return root;
    }
```

Para obtener el contexto (`Context`) en un fragmento no se usa `this` se debe usar `getActivity()`

`getActivity()` -> en un Fragmento regresa la Actividad con la que esta actualmente asociada. échale un ojo a [esto](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity())

por lo tanto

```
ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
```

Tendrías que cambiarlo por

```
ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
```

Comment: mmm viendo el articulo, lo que necesito no es un fragmento es una actividad, pero tengo el problema de que no se como exportar una navigation drawer a varias actividades

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo referencia a un Spinner, el cual no tiene una vista en la cual se encuentra:

```
   @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ruta = (Spinner) ruta.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

Regularmente debes tener un Layout donde tomar la referencia de tu vista, en este caso tu Spinner:

```
   @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_valorar); // dentro de main_activity.xml se debe encontrar definido tu Spinner.
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ruta = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

**Lo anterior aplica para una Activity pero en tu caso veo que extiende tu clase de Fragment:**

```
public class Valorar extends Fragment {
```

por lo tanto, lo anterior deberías realizarlo dentro del método `onCreateView()` :

```
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_valorar, container, false);
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ruta = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

---

Te puedo comentar también que desactivar la politica que no permite operaciones en el thread principal para una aplicación en producción no es buena practica.

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```